# slow php process

Tags: php, mysql, performance, function, process

I have a question regarding a call to a function that takes quite a while and I hope some can see if I did something criminal.

When I run the function GetEmailCue in the function below from sendletter.php it takes a about a minute or so to complete and I can't figure out why.

The emailcue db table only contain 2 emails.

```
         /******************************************
         * Sends a letter from the email cue
         * 
         * @param int       | The letter id
         *******************************************/
        function SendTheLetter($letter_id) {

            /*** Find the email cue based on the newsletter uid ***/
            $cue = new NewsletterHandler;
            $cue->GetLetterContent($letter_id);
            $cue->GetEmailCue($letter_id);

            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

            foreach($cue->email_row as $key => $value) { 
                mail($value, "Newsletter - ". date("d-m-Y"), $this->htmlTemplate, $headers);
                $sql_update = "UPDATE newsletter_emailcue SET time_recieved = NOW() WHERE email = '". $value ."'";
                SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql_update);                
            }
        }
```

This functions pull data from two other functions

GetLetterContent:

```
         /******************************************
         * Find all fields that belongs to a    
         * newsletter.
         * 
         * @param int       | The letter id
         *******************************************/
        function GetLetterContent($letter_id) { 

            $sql = "SELECT A.template, A.status, B.field_name, B.field_content FROM newsletter_items A, newsletter_fields B WHERE B.field_letter_uid = '". $letter_id ."'";           

            $result = SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

                    $this->content_markers["". $row["field_name"] .""] = $row["field_content"];
                    $template = $row["template"];
                }

                /*** Compile the letter with all the markers ***/
                $this->CompileLetter($letter_id, $template, $this->content_markers);
                return;                
        }
```

and

GetEmailCue:

```
         /******************************************
         * Get an entire email cue based on a 
         * newsletter id.
         * This functions is called from the send 
         * function.
         * 
         * @param int       | The letter id
         *******************************************/
        function GetEmailCue($letter_id) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM newsletter_emailcue WHERE mail_to_recieve = '". $letter_id ."' AND time_recieved = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' LIMIT 1";
            $result = SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql);

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
                $sql_update = "UPDATE newsletter_items SET status = 2 WHERE letter_id = '". $letter_id ."'";
                SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql_update);
            } else {              
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $this->email_row[] = $row["email"];
                }
            }

            return $this->email_row;
        }
```

It seems that GetEmailCue might be the issue, because if I comment it out in SendTheLetter the function is executed right away and if I run GetEmailCue directly from a file this function is also executed right away, but when I run it within SendTheLetter it takes for ever.

SendTheLetter function is again called from FindLetterToSend

```
         /******************************************
         * Finds all letters that have send status 1
         * which is pending to send.
         *******************************************/
        function FindLetterToSend() { 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM newsletter_items WHERE status = '1'";           
            $result = SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql);

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) { 
               Main::txtOutput("Der er ingen nyhedsbreve i udsendelseskøen!", "TXT_ERR");               

               /*** Let's clear the emailcue table - no need for the cue any more ***/
               SQLHandling::SQLquery("TRUNCATE TABLE newsletter_emailcue");               
            } else {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                    $this->SendTheLetter($row["letter_id"]);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
```

I am running it on my Ubuntu localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending E-Mails takes some time, but you said, that only two mails have been sent. This isn't much.

This code does an update on any email-line?

```
foreach($cue->email_row as $key => $value) { 
    mail($value, "Newsletter - ". date("d-m-Y"), $this->htmlTemplate, $headers);
    $sql_update = "UPDATE newsletter_emailcue SET time_recieved = NOW() WHERE email = '". $value ."'";
    SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql_update);                
}
```

Did you try to measure the runtime of the single code-parts with microtime function?

Comment: When an email is sent that email will get a timestamp in order to avoid him/her receiving the newsletter more than one time. The foreach updates the email just send...

I could try to measure the runtime.

Comment: $cue->GetEmailCue($letter_id) in the SendTheLetter have a runtime of
0.00030803680419922 and the foreach have a runtime of
60.888072013855 - this seems wild!

Comment: Thanks for the tip with runtime.. It seems that I have isolated the problem to be the mail function...
Can this be a setup in Ubuntu localhost?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer (I'm @ work) I think, that this could be the-mail-server itself. Maybe try to measure time of mail->submit. My ErrorHandler-Function does send emails too and always needs a certain time to do this. I don't know what kind of Mail-Class you are using, but maybe you have an option to queue emails and send all at once. What value does `foreach($cue->email_row as $key => $value) ` $value have? Is it an id?

Comment: The issue AFAIK is sendmail inside Ubuntu itself that have a delay for about 60 seconds which seems about right according to the runtime on mail... Or something with domain names and DNS etc. 

I installed sendemail with apt-get install and then ran the script again and it went through it right away! :) 

I have accepted your answer, because you tipped me about runtime which led me to the mail function! So thank you :)

Comment: Nice that I could help you out a little bit ;) TY